# What is the difference between GA Sessions and Users?

Tags: google-analytics, users

Specifically, the way I'm reading how Google describes both, I don't understand why both metrics don't have matching numbers.

Can some describe very specifically the difference between the two and why both report different numbers?

I wasn't able to find on answer about why these two metrics don't match numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Copy pasting this in (cf: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1257084?hl=en):

> Analytics measures both sessions and users in your account. Sessions represent the number of individual sessions initiated by all the users to your site. If a user is inactive on your site for 30 minutes or more, any future activity is attributed to a new session. Users that leave your site and return within 30 minutes are counted as part of the original session.
>
> The initial session by a user during any given date range is considered to be an additional session and an additional user. **Any future sessions from the same user during the selected time period are counted as additional sessions, but not as additional users.**

So this last line gives a bit of explanation as to why users and sessions differ.

Comment: Was going to answer in my own words with a link to source but in all honesty, the above quote from Google themselves is as good and clear enough explanation as any.